# Cannot use " { " Key

Tags: macbook, keyboard-layout, input-languages

I have a macbook pro with a Portuguese keyboard and I don't have the <kbd>{</kbd> key.  Can I bind `{` to another key?

If so how?

Comment: Welcome to SU, Carlos!  I'm curious how you wrote this post.  Can you just do whatever you did for that, permanently?

Comment: I presume he copy and pasted from another site or text. I don't think that would be an optimal solution. ;-)

Comment: I guess no C/Java programming for you, eh?  Time to take up Lisp instead?  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing with the built-in keyboard viewer and the Portuguese keyboard layout, it looks like <kbd>Option/alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> and <kbd>Option/alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> will type a **`{`** and **`}`**, respectively.

You can enable the keyboard viewer in System Preferences → Language and Text → Input Sources.  Check "Keyboard & Character Viewer" at the top of the list, and check "Show Input menu in menu bar".  This will put a new menu in your menu bar where you can enable the keyboard viewer.  You can hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Option</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and the on-screen keyboard will update in real-time; you might discover some other key sequences to type keys you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the settings, you can customize keyboard layouts with [Ukelele](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/14495/ukelele).